# GitHub Codespaces Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service workers: NotSupportedError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, service-worker, web-worker, codespaces

When I open a `README.md` Markdown Preview view in GitHub Codespaces on Google Chrome (as well as e.g. on Chromium-based Brave) I am getting:

`Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service workers: NotSupportedError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://....vscode-cdn.net/insider/.../out/vs/workbench/contrib/webview/browser/pre/') with script ('https://....vscode-cdn.net/insider/.../out/vs/workbench/contrib/webview/browser/pre/service-worker.js?v=4&vscode-resource-base-authority=vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net&remoteAuthority=codespaces+vorburger-...'): The user denied permission to use Service Worker..`

How can I grant permission to use Service Workers to `*.github.dev` / `*.vscode-cdn.net` in Chrom/Chromium/Brave?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same issue in chrome with Eclipse Che using vs code IDE
("Error loading webview: ... The user denied permission to use Service Worker")

fixed by **allowing third-party cookies** on the site in the browser settings (added an exclusion for the site)

the solution is taken from [here](https://github.community/t/the-user-denied-permission-to-use-service-worker-when-using-codespaces/195324)

settings from [support google com](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647)

an example in [pictures](https://support.cloudhq.net/how-to-enable-3rd-party-cookies-in-google-chrome-browser/)

Answer (score 2):

For GitHub Codespaces, in Firefox, I had to disable "Enhanced Tracking Protection" for the site, and that is all. To do so, click on the shield icon which is to the left of the displayed web address.